# Javascript - The quickest and most efficient way to replace object-based values in text

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var obj = {
    a: "text",
    b: "text 2",
    c: "text 3",
    ...
}
```

and I have a bunch of strings that look like this:

```
var stringA = "http://{{a}}.something.com/",
    stringB = "http://something.{{b}}.com/",
    stringC = "http://something.com/{{c}}";
```

I want to replace `{{(\w)}}` with it's equivalent by going through `obj` and checking if it has my matched value for every string, but I'm sure there is a better and faster way to do so.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Douglas Crockford wrote a function called `supplant` that does almost exactly what you want. I've altered the function slightly to match your double curly braces  -

```
if (typeof String.prototype.supplant !== 'function') {
    String.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
        return this.replace(/{{([^{}]*)}}/g, function (a, b) {
            var r = o[b];
            return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
        });
    };
}

var obj = {
    a: "text",
    b: "text 2",
    c: "text 3"
}

var stringA = "http://{{a}}.something.com/",
    stringB = "http://something.{{b}}.com/",
    stringC = "http://something.com/{{c}}";

alert(stringA.supplant(obj));
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/saZGg/

Comment: any way to map deep objects with dot notation?

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = /(.*){{(\w)}}(.*)/.exec(stringA);
arr[2] = obj[arr[2]];
arr.shift(); // remove full string at start
var newString = arr.join("");
```

- Generally run a regular expression on the string,
- execute and turn it into an array.
- Swap one of the groups for the value in your object hash
- join the array into your "compiled" string.

Or use one of the `.replace` solutions which is arguebly more elegant.

Comment: `.exec` will return the string itself as its first argument, so you'll end up with the unaltered string prepended.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
function format(str, values) {
    return str.replace(/{{(\w)}}/g, function(match, name) {
        return values[name] || match;
    });
}
```

It just looks up whether the object has a property with the captured name. If not, nothing is replaced.

Usage:

```
var str = format(stringA, obj);
```